# Image rendered and saved is not same

Tags: rendering, image, transparency

Trying to figure out what can be done to render this effect with transparent background.
It looks like the render itself done correct in Blender, but when you save the image and open it - it loose the part that dont have background. Any help will appreciated

Rendered image

[image: Rendered]

Saved Image

[image: Saved]

[image]

Comment: Ya. Thx alot. Good enough to understand. Did not know about emission pixels and transparency issues

Answer (score -2):

it seems to me you have selected a output format that doesn't support transparency like jpeg maybe , try export your files in png/exr/tiff ( png beeing the easier to handle , but you should lean toward EXR if your rig is emissive on a transparent background , png won't handle it )

Comment: Thx. Its a png. But looking at the link given by Gordon in comment - its seems emission pixels and transparency issue. But i will try also with tiff and exr.

Comment: That's not a real answer if you had actually dipped into the problem. The problem here is not having transparency in the file, it's having emission over transparency and your recommendation of using a PNG is the worst choice for that (apart from that it's already a PNG in the question).

Comment: Saved with an edit ;)

Comment: edited before your comment thought ;)

Comment: Thx alot for your answers. Did not know this before, never rendered emission on transparent bg before. This effect is used by streamers in YT thumbnails, so some did it with transparency and get this. I will test it out with other formats and update documentation. Will try from PC to select Gordon's comment as answer, as i cant rn on mobile